# JQuery Cookies Creation...Check if cookie already has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to create a cookie with JQuery:

```
$.cookie('MyCookieName', 'myValueHere');
```

It works fine but as I have the value assign to a random number it's generating a new one every reload.

What I need to do is check if cookie has a value and if it's not empty then don't create a new one or generate any new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($.cookie('MyCookieName') == null) {
    $.cookie('MyCookieName','MyCookieValue');
}
```

You can also add expire time and path in options.

```
$.cookie('MyCookieName','MyCookieValue', { path: '[path here]', expires: [days] });
```

Then you can be sure, that cookies won't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for a value already set in an if statement like this

```
if($.cookie('MyCookieName') == null) {
   //it doesnt exist
} else {
   // do something else maybe
}
```

Thats if your plugin [for example this one](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) returns `null` when the cookie is not found

Comment: Actally my plugin returns nothing is the cookie is not found

Comment: can you link to your plugin ... define `nothing`

Answer (score 1):

to avoid misunderstandings it's better to use exact comparison:

```
if($.cookie('MyCookieName') === null) { //some stuff }
```

Comment: Actally my plugin returns nothing is the cookie is not found